# How to use the crypto processor on the dev board?

Tags: google-coral

On the data sheet, the SoM comes with an ATECC608A crypographic coprocessor, but there are no documentations on how to use it. Are there some usecase for this HW and any instructions on how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

This library is included in the coral-cloud repo. It is generally installed with the Coral cloudiot package (python3-coral-cloudiot) but could also directly installed with python3-cryptoauthlib.

```
echo "deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt coral-cloud-stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/coral-cloud.list
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-coral-cloudiot
```

The sdk can be found here: https://github.com/MicrochipTech/cryptoauthlib

Answer (score 0):

The internal ECC608 seems to be connected to the internal i2c (I2C1). The external i2c busses are I2C2 and I2C3.
If adapted to bus I2C1 (bus 0), the example code finds an ECC608 at address 0x60 on my device and I can read out the serial number of the chip.
Although - the ECC608 has many configuration and key-storage options. If haven't found any documentation on the internal use of the chip yet.

Comment: Here is an example on how you can use the sdk: https://coral.googlesource.com/coral-cloud/+/0834d86345bb64ccaa7381ba2cc01b3b9213ba19/python/coral-cloudiot/coral/cloudiot/ecc608.py

Comment: Thank you, this module already includes the usage of I2C1. I had a quick check with a Jupyter-Notebook and I was able to get the serial num, a generated public key, a signed message and a JWT. Works like a charm.